# Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, .net, timer, windows-services

I have created and installed a service a couple of times. Initially it was working fine, but after some changes in the service Code it start giving the error when I restart the service in Services.msc :

> Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a    timely fashion

Code:

```
public partial class AutoSMS : ServiceBase
{
    public AutoSMS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        eventLog1.Clear();

        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "MySource", "MyNewLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
        eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";

        Timer checkForTime = new Timer(5000);
        checkForTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
        checkForTime.Enabled = true;

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In onStop.");
    }


    void checkForTime_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string Time = "15:05:00";
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Time, "HH:mm:ss",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (DateTime.Now == dateTime) ;
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(Time);
    }
}
```

Here is my main method code

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new AutoSMS() 
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

I also tried the following steps :

- Go to Start > Run > and type regedit
- Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
- With the control folder selected, right click in the pane on the right and - select new DWORD Value
- Name the new DWORD: ServicesPipeTimeout
- Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify
- Click Decimal, type '180000', and then click OK
- Restart the computer

I used to install and uninstall it with following command :

```
installutil AutoSMS.exe

installutil /u AutoSMS.exe
```

Comment: What does the Windows event log say? Or does it say `Error 1053`? It could be a rights issue. Try running the service as `Local System` user.

Comment: In the future it might be useful to use System.Diagnotstics.Debugger.Launch() in the Main() method so you can work with the debugger.

Answer (score 55):

In my case, I was publishing service while it was in **debug mode.**

**Solution was:**

- Changing solution to **release mode**
- Uninstall old service with command `InstallUtil -u WindowsServiceName.exe`
- installing service again  `InstallUtil -i WindowsServiceName.exe`

It worked perfectly after.

Comment: Man I scratched my head on this for a while. Checking config files and event logs to no end until I read this answer and kicked myself for forgetting to flip the build to release. This worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me too. How it is possible :D Thank you after many years

Answer (score 41):

As others have pointed out, this error can have a multitude of causes.  But in the hopes that this will help somebody out, I'll share what happened in our case.  For us, our service had been upgraded to .NET 4.5, but the server did not have .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: Multitude is correct. The error could appear if you have errors within your service. So related to your code rather than the framework.

Comment: Around the topic of .NET - we received this message because our windows service was running on .NET 2.0, when we moved it onto a Windows 2019 instance (which didn't have .NET 2.0 installed), we got this error. It took us a full day to figure this one out - so hope this can help someone else out.

Comment: I had 4.5 installed but was missing the 4.5.2 update.

Comment: Tacking on that in my case, the flavor of cause for this error was that the EXE was not implementing ServiceBase OnStart or OnStop

Comment: This is still a relevant answer. Some of our services stopped working after an in-place upgrade to Server 2016. Installing a missing .NET Framework runtime (4.7.2 in our case) got them working again.

Answer (score 36):

After spending some time on the issue, trying solutions that didn't work, I run into [this blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2011/03/03/debugging-windows-service-timeout-error-1053.aspx). It suggests to wrap the service initialization code in a try/catch block, like this, and adding EventLog

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace WindowsService
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                { 
                    new Service1() 
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, uninstall the old service, redeploy the service with these modifications. Start the service and check out the Event Viewer/Application logs.  You'll see what the real problem is, which is the underlying reason for the timeout.

Comment: Good idea but in my case it doesn't log anything.. still this annoying message and no hints about it!

Comment: In my case the case that init the service is loading custom config files and the path was set up as relative and for some reason the service didn't like that. changing the path to full path worked.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  It helped me down the road.  (In my case, the problem was a directory permissions issue).

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same issue and was not at all sure how to resolve it. Yes this occurs because an exception is being thrown from the service, but there are a few general guidelines that you can follow to correct this:

- Check that you have written the correct code to start the service:

  `ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
  ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
  { 
      new WinsowsServiceToRun() 
  };
  ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);`
- You need to ensure that there is some kind of infinite loop running in the class WinsowsServiceToRun
- Finally, there may be some code which is not logging anything and closing the program abruptly (which was the case with me), in this case you will have to follow the old school of debugging which needed to write a line to a source (text/db/wherever). What I faced was that since the account running the service was not "Admin", the code was just falling off and not logging any exceptions in case it was trying to write to "Windows Event Log" even though the code was there to log exceptions. Admin privilege is actually not needed for logging to Even Log but it is needed to define the source. In case source of the event is not already defined in the system and the service tries to log it for the first time without admin privilege it fails. To solve this follow below steps:

  1. Open command prompt with admin privilege
  2. Paste the command : `eventcreate /ID 1 /L APPLICATION /T INFORMATION  /SO <<Source>> /D "<<SourceUsingWhichToWrite>>"`
  3. Press enter
  4. Now start the service

Comment: nice answer, in my case the problem is  `ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);` line is never accessed. since the service is also designed so it can run in command line I missed the conf. one missed configuration and wasted hours...

Comment: @mkb: Yes a miss config does take out a lot of time. Out of the above mentioned I faced two and took me hours to figure the same. Thanks for upvoting and the edit.

Comment: @mkb What config do you mean?

Comment: @abatonime at that time I added a key  to the app.config to decide whether it will run as windows service or as a common CommandLine program. something like runasservice="true" and when I set it to false ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun); is never called

Comment: @mkb OK thanks. In my case I used *System.Diagnotstics.Debugger.Launch()* to start debugging in VS and found out there was an exception thrown because the CurrentDirectory is set to windows/system32

Comment: @Abatonime well done, I can feel it, damn directory errors :)

Comment: I was fixing a service for a coworker, unfortunately in debug build it didn't call the `ServiceBase.Run` method, just called the method for processing directly. `#if !DEBUG` should be used sparingly.

Comment: Thanks this saved me hours! In my case the missing part is ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);. It was commented.

Answer (score 10):

I have just tried this code locally in .Net 4.5 and the service starts and stops correctly for me. I suspect your problem may be around creating the EventLog source.

The method:

```
EventLog.SourceExists("MySource")
```

requires that the user running the code must be an administrator, as per the documentation here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7y6sy21(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7y6sy21%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Check that the service is running as a user that has administrator privileges.

Comment: I started the service.msc with administrator account and also tried to install and uninstall service.exe with command prompt as RUn as Administrator ...Still it is not working

Comment: You need to check to see what account the actual service is running under, rather than running the command prompt to install the service as an admin. In Services, right click on the AutoSMS service and select _Properties_ -> _Log On_ tab. Try selecting the top radio radio button for _Local System_ account

Comment: .net framework version is the key for the solution. nothing else. i replaced .net framework 4.0 with 4. 5 after that service started without any issues.

Comment: When I commented out `EventLog` thing, my service started working. But I need `EventLog` though I ran command prompt as an Administrator. I think running command prompt as an Admin doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 9):

It is because of the Microsoft Windows Service Control, it controls sometimes the state of the services. If the service don´t send a respond in 30 seconds, then you will have this error.

You can modified the registry, so the service will have more time to respond

```
Go to Start > Run > and type regedit
Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
With the control folder selected, right click in the pane on the right and select new DWORD Value
Name the new DWORD: ServicesPipeTimeout 
Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify
Click Decimal, type '180000', and then click OK
Restart the computer
```

Or be sure that in that moment there is not another process talking with the service, maybe there is a conflict I don´t know

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to register a .NET core 3.1 executable as a Windows Service, please ensure that you added the nuget package Microsoft.Extension.Hosting.WindowsServices in version 3.1.7 or above and initialize the hostBuilder like in the following example:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] arguments)
        {
            IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(arguments);
            hostBuilder.UseWindowsService();
            hostBuilder.Build().Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you are able to install the executable and start it as a windows service:

```
sc.exe create ConsoleApp1 binPath= "<BIN_PATH>\ConsoleApp1.exe"
```

Comment: The important part here is `.UseWindowsService()` should be called LAST (right before `.Build()`). Thanks!

Comment: Saved my next 8 hours :)

Answer (score 5):

I was getting exactly same issue, All I have done is to to change the Debug mode to Release while compiling the dll. This has solved my probelm, how/why? I dont know I have already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338049/the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion) on SO

Comment: I encountered the exact same problem and solution.  I'm not sure why this works, but thank you!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Was releasing the DLLs using debug mode encountered the issue. After building solution using release mode. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

After spending too much time on this issue. I found the `EventLog` cause all that mess although I used it properly.

Whoever tackle this issue, I would suggest you to get rid of the `EventLog`.
Use better tools like "**log4net**".

Answer (score 5):

In the case I ran into this morning, the culprit was a malformed config file. The config file had an close comment tag without the open comment tag. So, double check your config files for errors.

Comment: Yees, that's the issue that I had. But to realize details of the problem, you can check Event viewer > Windows Logs > Application. There was the stacktrace helped me to update the config file.

Answer (score 4):

Also, you need to check your configuration file content.

You need to check below the section.

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
</startup>
```

Coz above section need to match with yours .net framework.

Answer (score 2):

Check `ConnectionStrings` if you are using `EntityFramework` or any other means to initiate database connections at the service startup.

In my case when i got the error `Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion` this is what was going wrong:

I was using EntityFramework and had the connection strings wrong. So basically at startup the EntityFramework failed to connect to the database using the incorrect Connection String and timed out.

**Just had to replace the database connection string with the correct one and it worked fine.**

Did not need any framework update or any other system/configuration change at all.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Basically make sure the Log on user is set to the right one. However it depends how the account infrastructure is set. In my example it's using AD account user credentials.

In start up menu search box search for 'Services'
 -In Services find the required service
 -right click on and select the Log On tab
 -Select 'This account' and enter the required content/credentials
 -Ok it and start the service as usual

[image]

Comment: I wish this answer was higher up. As this was my case even though it took 30s for the misleading error 1053 to occur.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed .Net 4.6 on my WindowsServer computer and the error was fixed.

Your control should be this way:

1. Check the .net version of your WindowsService
2. Then check the .net version of your computer
3. Match that version, since it's probably not matched

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions for this problem [It fixed issue at my end and my application is **JAVA** based application ]:

1) check your application is pointing to correct java version(check the java version and path in your application).

**OR**

2)check the configured java version i.e check whether it is 32-bit version or 64-bit version(based on your application). if you are using 32-bit then you should use 32-bit version JSL, else JSL will cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by an uncaught exception in the service itself. (Configuration file errors eg). Opening a command prompt and starting the service executable manually wil perhaps reveal the exception been thrown.

Comment: `Problem signature: P1: YourServiceName.exe ... P4: System.Configuration ... P9: System.TypeInitialization`

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I had to stop my existing service to update code. after updating the code and while START the Service I got the same error "Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion".

But this got resolve after RESTARTING THE MACHINE.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question,
I used to write my own VB.NET windows service, and it has no issue to start on MS windows 7 and MS windows 10.

I have this issue when I install the windows services on latest MS windows 10 patch. The reason the windows service doesn't run it is because the .NET version that needed for the window services to run is not presented in the installed PC.

After you have installed the windows services. go to the install folder for example C:\Program files (x86)\Service1\Service1.exe and double click to run it. If there is missing .NET framework package, it will prompt the user to download it. Just download and and wait for it to install.

After that restart the windows services in services.msc. 
Hope this answer will help someone who face the issue. I know issue is caused by .NET framework version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add my solution to this.
Must admit, I use an additional configuration file ("ServiceIni.xml") with some settings to be changed by user on the fly.
When I faced this error I made a research and did following:

1. Changed Program.cs to following code:

```
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                {
                new MyService()
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogChanges($"Error - {ex.Message}\nInner - {ex.InnerException}");
            }
        }

        static void LogChanges(string message)
        {
            string LogPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "MyServiceLog.txt";
            using (StreamWriter wr = File.AppendText(LogPath))
            {
                wr.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
```

2. Then I discovered an exception on startup from the log (it showed even error line number :)):

```
Error - Configuration system failed to initialize
Inner - System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: A section using 'configSource' may contain no other attributes or elements. (C:\...\bin\Release\MyService.exe.Config line 24)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
```

3. It appeared that one of builds changed my App.config file from:

```
<!-- Setting to use appSettings from external file -->
  <appSettings configSource="ServiceIni.xml"/>
```

to

```
  <appSettings configSource="ServiceIni.xml">
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
```

which generated this error.
Fixing back to original App.config solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have .NET 6, please read it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service

when you create a service in command line, use like this

```
sc.exe create SERVICE_NAME binPath="C:\....\bin\Release\net6.0\win-x64\SERVICE_NAME.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was about caching configuration which is set in the App.config file. Once I removed below lines from the App.config file, the issue was resolved.

```
<cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="MyCacheManager">
<cacheManagers>
  <add name="MyCacheManager" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheManager, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
       expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="60"
       maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="50000"
       numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="1000"
       backingStoreName="NullBackingStore" />
</cacheManagers>
<backingStores>
  <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
       name="NullBackingStore" />
</backingStores>
```

Comment: i am facing same problem but not in all systems. i have created a windows service. its running fine most of the system. in couple of systems alone i am facing this error 1503. i tried regedit, cmd window- event. no use!

Comment: did you try removing these parts from the specific systems .config file?

Comment: i dont have such lines"cachingConfiguration" in my .config file. i am trying to install .net 4.5 framework in those systems. it is downloading

Comment: oh, I see. sorry, I don't know how it is resolved. :/

Comment: i used install shield le to generate setup file for this windows service. when i was developing this windows service from my system which has VS2012. .net framework 4.5. i assumed that this service requires min .net framework 4.0. when i install in other system which has .net 4.0 may caused this issue. i am not anand, i am pranesh.

Comment: i got the solution for error 1503. The issue is .net framework version. my service required .net framework 4.5 but in system it was 4.0. so the service start issued the error 1503. now rectified!! some one shall get a clue for their problem from this! thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I have removed

EventLog.Exists

and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I apparently had some extra symbols in my App.config file that I did not notice when building my solution.
So I recomend to check the configuration file for errors first before taking steps with changing registry keys, switching configuration modes, etc.

Comment: By extra symbols you means additional settings or invalid junk characters (which makes the xml structure invalid)? Can you please share the details about then in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had two services running who were accidentally coupled to the same EventSource `eventLog.Source = "MySource";` After uninstalling both services, and reinstalling the one that suffered from error 1053, my service started up normally.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the service starting code is correct,

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
{ 
    new WinsowsServiceToRun() 
};
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

Also, remove any debug codes.
ie,

```
  #If Debug
         ...
         ...
         ...
        #else
         ...
         ...
        #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
Unchecking "Sing the ClickOnce manifest", "Sign the assembly" and "Enable ClickOnce security settings" in project properties helped

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the one with `appsettings.json` not copying to release build folder during build and simple putting it into the `...\bin\Release` folder and copying `launchSettings.json` content to `appsettings.json` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Seems like when starting the service the main thread shouldnt be the main worker thread.
By simply creating a new thread and handing the main work to that thread solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I scratched my head to clear this error
This error might be caused if you are debugging it in the code like

```
static void Main()
{
 #if DEBUG
            MailService service = new MailService();
             service.Ondebug();
 #else
             ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
             ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
             {
                 new MailService()
             };
             ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
 #endif
         }
     }
```

After clearing the `if,else` and `endif` in the code like this the error has not appeared again....hope it helps....

```
static void Main()
{

    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new MailService()
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As nobody has mentioned I will add it (even if it is a stupid mistake).
In case you are on Windows 10 you don't usually need to restart, but

-> Make sure to CLOSE any open properties pages of the "services"-window in case you have just installed the service (and still have opened the properties page of the old service).

I'm talking about this window:

[image: Services list]

After closing all services windows and re-trying -> it worked. In contrast to the OP I got `Error 1053` basically immediately  (without windows waiting on anything)

Answer (score 0):

Install the .net framework 4.5! It worked for me.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57768

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was due to the code trying to find and read a file that didn't exist in the location it was searching in, due to it being installed and running as a service.

This simple change was to change this part of code from:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

To

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

To sum up why this worked nicely is because `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` points to `C:\Windows\System32` which is the default Windows service path and `Domain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` points to the application folder which contains the application’s `.exe` file to run the application.

please read article if interested on how i managed to find a solution as the code worked locally but not as a service.
https://www.getcoding.co.uk/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/

Comment: Also, this question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, my approach hasn't been previously mentioned in the past, as all the replies didn't solve my issue and was still persistent when applying and testing other approaches, The flaw in mine was the actual code as it worked locally but not when trying to run as a service. No where else documented this solution, so i thought i should as it may or may not be the solution for other people as there are numerous reasons why this could happen and mine happed to be because of the code itself.

Answer (score -1):

this error can be caused due to various reasons. to identify the reason add try/ catch when service is run.

```
        try
            {
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                { 
                    new Service1() 
                };
                <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun</span>);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.ToString(), <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">EventLogEntryType.Error</span>);
            }
```