# The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion if Debug dll used

Tags: c#, dll, compilation, windows-services, release-mode

I was trying to deploy a windows service on my machine, but when I was trying to start it I got following error.

"Windows could not start the 'myService' on Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

After a bit of research I found out that I was complining my project with Debug option, the moment I changed it to 'Release' mode all was good and working. I can not make sense of this behaviour so I searched the net and found this [debug-vs-release-in-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90871/debug-vs-release-in-net) but even this does not explain why my window service was failling to start if i was using debug mode's dll

If anyone can explain it that will help me lot to understand how this actually works thanks.

Comment: Do you have a call to [Debug.Assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or similar) in your OnStart() method?

Comment: @ahsant Have you found out anything more about this?  I'm also interested in why this happens, I saw this recently.