# Correct way to start Windows Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service, windows-services

```
    #if DEBUG
            MainService service1 = new MainService();
            service1.onDebug();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
            ConfigurationSync.logDebugMessage(logMessageType.message, "Starting main service thread");

#else
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new MainService()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            ConfigurationSync.logDebugMessage(logMessageType.message, "Starting main service thread");

#endif
```

I have created my first windows service and I am wondering what the correct way is to start the service in the Program.cs file.

The code supplied above is what was suggested to me by an online tut, `#if debug` running while testing in Visual Studio and the `else` block running when built in release mode and installed on the server.
The problem is, it doesn't seem to run on the server after install if I don't use the code in the `#if debug` code block.
If i run the code as supplied above it says the service has started but nothing seems to happen, while if I only run what's in the `debug` block the service runs but I get an error on the server `"Service failed to start in a timely manner"`

Any help would be appreciated

Update:
In my mainservice I have a function that kicks off all the features of the service, this function is `startSoftwareUpdates();`

These are the functions I have in `MainService`:

```
        public MainService()
    {
        startSoftwareUpdates();

        public void onDebug()
    {

        OnStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        startSoftwareUpdates();
    }
```

Update 3:

So I have reshuffled `MainService` as follows:

```
        public MainService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void onDebug()
    {

        OnStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            startSoftwareUpdates();
        }).Start();
    }
```

What kind of problems might I run into with this approach? I'd like the Thread to run infinitely too...

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen if your service runs?

Comment: Well for one, I'd expect the ConfigurationSync.LogDebugMessage in the else block to fire, which it doesn't. Then I have several other logs located in the mainservice class which also doesn't fire which leads me to believe somewhere within the else block the code breaks...

Comment: Well you will never see your log because the service never completes the `Run`. That is normal. If your service should be doing things, you should not do it all on start. The method should start up another thread to do the work.

Comment: Well to be clear startSoftwareUpdates(); downloads software updates then fires off several timers, this whole process takes less than a second...

Comment: Processes exit when the last foreground thread exits. If all you're leaving behind after returning from `OnStart` is a *background* thread, that's not going to work well.

Comment: So Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false; ?

Comment: @Tiaan Have you wrapped your ```startSoftwareUpdates()``` in a ```Try/Catch``` to see if an exception is thrown?

Comment: @James yeah I have, there are no exceptions occurring...

Comment: Does ```OnStart``` run without you calling ```OnDebug```? Meaning, if you just instantiate ```MainService```, does is automatically call ```OnStart```?

Comment: No it does not, and notably even with nothing other than a log executing in OnStart running sc Start gives an error failed to start in a timely fashion

Comment: Are you still trying to log in the ```Program``` file or did you move that to ```OnStart```?

Comment: I have logs in the onStart of the servoce and there's a log before and after I try to start the service in the Program.cs file.

Comment: The log before I try to start the service in Program.cs fires but after that nothing...

Answer (score 3):

Nothing looks *wrong* with your code. If you could post some more of the code that is inside of your `MainService()` constructor, that'd be helpful considering that could be where the issue is.

However, when I build these services, instead of the `#if DEBUG` route, I generally do something like this

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
{
      //**** this is for debugging in console mode
}
else
{
     //*** this is for running as a Windows service
     var ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
     {
          new ServiceHome()
     };
     ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

To be clear, I don't expect this to resolve your issue as the code you posted above seems to do the same thing, just in a different manner. I'm posting this to give you a different way to accomplish what you did above.

If I had to guess, I'd say the issue is in your `MainService` constructor.

**Edit**

I don't believe the issue is with any of the code that you've written. The error you're getting is caused by a number of potential issues, so it's tough to tell you exactly what it is. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228307/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-time) is a link that has some solutions for you to try. Also, you should try to find the error in the `Event Log`, assuming you're on a windows machine. That will have a bit more detail to the issue most of the time.

Comment: That makes sense, like I said this is my first project so it's possible I was misinformed, I have edited my post to show the code in my MainService