# Start-Service cmdlet: get underlying error in case of failure

Tags: powershell, windows-services

Say that I want to start MSSSQLSERVER service. this is done in PowerShell via the `Start-Service` cmdlet.
Sometimes services fail to start due to an error like in the example below. 
What I'm interested in is the root cause of the failure, while `start-service` seems to be returning the powershell exception, a generic wrapper that does not contain *error-specific information*.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> start-service MSSQLSERVER
start-service : Failed to start service 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) (MSSQLSERVER)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Service MSSQLSERVER
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

To get the root cause of the problem, we have to resort to `net start` command, that brings us back to the old-days that should be forgotten with PowerShell.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>NET START MSSQLSERVER
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is starting.
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service could not be started.

A service specific error occurred: 17051.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3547.
```

Is there a way to see the **underlying** error thrown by the service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As *I.T Delinquent* stated, the error can be found in the exception, however in this case it will be stored in the inner exception(s):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

try
{
    Start-Service -Name "MSSQLSERVER"
}
catch
{
    $msg = @()
    $err = $_.Exception
    do {
        $msg += $err.Message
        $err = $err.InnerException
    } while ($err)

    Write-Verbose "Failed to start service: $($msg -join ' - ')"
}
```

Comment: I found searching can be more reliable with `NativeErrorCode` (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228307/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-time)) so I use `"Error $($err.NativeErrorCode): $($err.Message)"`

Comment: @davetapley Thanks for the addition, for service operations it should work, but please note that `NativeErrorCode` is not available with all exceptions (types)

Comment: @mhu, I can't able to start my service using above code. Even i can able to start the service by manually too.

Comment: @LakshminarayananS This question/answer is more about getting the error when a service won't start, so what is the error message you get when running this code?

Comment: @mhu, I did configure wrongly, thats why service failed to restart.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be good for you to check out this [link](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-04-10-Powershell-exceptions-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/)

But basically, you can use a Try/Catch statement and output the message from the error, something like this:

```
try{
    Start-Service MSSQLSERVER -ErrorAction Stop
}catch{
    $PSItem.Exception.Message
}
```