# Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion, when intalled and ran a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to install a WCF service using this batch file below, the service is installed successfully, but threw the Error 1053 when ran

I've tried,
-Adding a ServicePipeTimeout DWord in the registry editor,
-Checking for System File Corruptions using sfc /scannow command,
-Resetting Network Cache and Configurations,
-Getting Ownership of the Application,
-Using Release Build instead of debug.

none of the above solutions resolved the error

This is the code I am using in the batch file

```
ECHO USAGE:
ECHO        %0 [option]
ECHO        r (or R) to have services installed from "Release" path. Release will also be added to service names. It will install services from debug path if nothing is specified.
ECHO.
ECHO.

SET Mode=Debug
IF "%1"=="R" (SET Mode=Release) 
IF "%1"=="r" (SET Mode=Release)

SET serviceUserName=user1
SET password=password
SET net4Path=%CD%
ECHO Installing Xignite Service
SET servicePath="%~dp0\path\to\ServiceHost.exe"
SET serviceName=ServiceHostSvc
SC create %serviceName% binPath= %servicePath% DisplayName= "Service1-"%Mode%
SC description %serviceName% "Description here."
SC CONFIG %serviceName% obj= %serviceUserName% password= %password% type= own
ECHO  Service1 Installed
ECHO.
SC START %serviceName%

pause
```

Is there anything else can i do to resolve the error?

Comment: Please refer this article if it can work for you.
https://www.get-itsolutions.com/the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/

Comment: You can take a look at the solutions provided in [this article](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/) and the content discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228307/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-time?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there could be some exception in the beginning of the service code. Try to add more logs in the beginning to see till where the execution is reaching.